# What causes 'If binding is greater than request or backing bean scope, it can cause inconsistencies.' Warning in ADF

Tags: oracle, scope, oracle-adf, uicomponents

I am working with one of the jsff page in ADF, which contains one of the popup and it has binding with it's managed bean.

```
  <af:popup id="p11"
                  binding="#{pageFlowScope.managedbean.rollBackConfirmPopop}">
```

in managedbean.java class

The definition lies

```
 private RichPopup rollBackConfirmPopop;

public void setRollBackConfirmPopop(RichPopup rollBackConfirmPopop) {
    this.rollBackConfirmPopop = rollBackConfirmPopop;
}

public RichPopup getRollBackConfirmPopop() {
    return rollBackConfirmPopop;
}
```

I have referred one of the post, which illustrates about the problem with serializable and thread safe issue with the UI component and suggested to generalize the declaration of rollBackConfirmPopop to trininad component class as

```
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util.ComponentReference class
```

After following the approach, I have done the changes as below:

```
     private ComponentReference rollBackConfirmPopop;

         public void setRollBackConfirmPopop1(RichPopup rollBackConfirmPopop) {
    this.rollBackConfirmPopop = ComponentReference.newUIComponentReference(rollBackConfirmPopop);

}

public RichPopup getRollBackConfirmPopop() {
    if (rollBackConfirmPopop!=null)
      {
        return (RichPopup) rollBackConfirmPopop.getComponent();
      }
      return null; 

}
```

Because of serializable and thread safe issue, it leads to memory leaks. I tried the above approach. But warning is still present. Please help me to solve the approach and understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have binded your managed bean with a pageflow scope. Try using requestScope or backingBeanScope to solve the problem.
For a detailed information, visit this [link](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/rules-and-best-practices-for-jsf-component-binding-in-adf/).

Comment: Yes I have gone through the link, from there only I got idea related to componentReference class. I have used the approached mentioned in the link and posted above. What I understood is, If you are assigning bindings with pageflowscope, it will lead to memory leaks. Mostly pageflowscope is used when u need to hold the value in the entire task flow. If some where you do not need to hold values for entire task flow and if the value is needed in the current page only then we should use request scope or backing bean scope.

Comment: I was searching a way that can we avoid the warning by having page flow scope.Is there any design time solution to avoid the warning with having the page flow scope.